# How to nest style="font-weight:bold...." in every row when I have dictionary for css properties?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am very new to Django so sorry for quetsion. I have passed from view to template dictionary like

```
{"font-weight":"bold","background-color":"red" ....}
```

and i have inside template generated rows for some data and for every row I have one dictionary like above. How to nest style="font-weight:bold...." in every row when I have dictionary for css properties?

Comment: -1. Why would you *do* this? Style attributes should be defined in CSS stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of CSS generated from the view but you can try something like:

```
# cotext dict
{ 'extra_style': 'color: red; font-weight: bold;' }

# in template
<tr style="{{ extra_style }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in the view:

```
'css': {"font-weight": "bold", "background-color": "red"}
```

And in the template:

```
<tr style="{% for k, v in css.items %}{{ k }}: {{ v }}; {% endfor %}">
```